Sphinx: rST inline literal interpreted as code?
According to Docutils, double backticks around text is equivalent to the :literal: role: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#literal
They show an example that these are equivalent:
``text``
:literal:`text`

Separately, they have a :code: role that appears to be intended for use for inline code: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#code
This role (and the code-block) directive appear to be treated as the <literal> doctree element. But I can't find anything that says all literals are code.
In the Sphinx documentation for inline markup, it says to use backticks for inline code samples: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#inline-markup
When Sphinx is writing HTML, it looks to me like it's interpreting any literal that isn't 'kbd' as code: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/df3d94ffdad09cc2592caccd179004e31aa63227/sphinx/writers/html5.py#L645
So it's rendering all literals surrounded by double backticks in HTML using the code element, like:
<code>some text in a literal</code>

I don't believe this is intended by Docutils - it looks like Docutils intends that all code is a literal but not all literals are code. For my purposes, I would rather literals render as something distinct that I can style appropriately, but not <code>, because the code element has additional semantic meaning that doesn't apply in my case. (i.e. we use it for a lot of things that we want to represent in monospace that isn't actually code.)
I'm wondering if anyone can shed light on why Sphinx has decided that all literals are code? (Or where I may be missing something and reaching an incorrect conclusion?)

Indeed, the preexisting semantic markup for literal/code elements (both inline and block flavour) rendered to HTML look visually similar.  They might  look distinct when rendered to other output formats.
If you really did want "code" (whatever that implies) then suggest double backticks wrapped around inline code, or the .. code-block:: directive for blocks.  Leave roles like :kbd: for the intended purpose.
Maybe you don't actually want to hijack a preexisting element.  Use the .. role:: directive to declare your own semantic elements (invisibly, at top of page, or via include):
.. role:: country

.. role:: city

then use those new roles in the page:
:city:`London`, the capital of :country:`England` and 
the :country:`United Kingdom`, is a 21st-century city
with history stretching back to Roman times.

and paired with a mystyles.css file in _static folder:
.city {
  font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold; background-color:yellow;
}
.country {
  font-family:monospace; font-weight:bold; background-color: orange;
}

may give what you want:

a lot cheaper than via a full blown extension.
